# Can we disinfect the shul and the ha aron kodesh ? How best?

Tags: synagogue

In the wake of the Coronarovirus epidemics, can we carry out a professional disinfection of the shul's sanctuary and of the Aron Kodesh, specifically the 3 Sifrei ha Torah and their mantels ?
How is it best to proceed halachically ?

Comment: If you have such suspicion of live virus particulate on the Torahs, you should be closing your shul immediately! Stay away!

Comment: I'm sure your Rav is in contact with medical professionals on how to proceed.

Comment: No amount of precaution and disinfectant can save you if haShem wants you to have that thing. On the other hand you could be perfectly safe straight in Wuhan. Now isn't that emunah?

Comment: @Ilja Just because one must have bitachon doesn’t mean that one is exempt from hishtadlus.